# Why are the junctions where ADC pins connect to PCB board ignored in thermocouple cold jucntion conmpensation calcutaions?

Tags: thermocouple

Why are the junctions where ADC pins connect to PCB tracks ignored in thermocouple cold junction calculations?

Comment: How do you know they are? Please provide information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the junction between the exotic thermocouple alloy wires and the "real-world" that is the source of the cold-junction error factor. Once the signal has proceeded through that junction, it is just like any other millivolt signal.

Here in modern times we have special chips that measure the cold-junction temperature and apply the correction factor. You kids don't know how nice you have things these days!  :-)

Comment: The magical part that I had been ignoring all along: "exotic thermocouple alloy wires". P.S. We kids also have internet :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is the transition from intentionally mismatched materials (the thermocouple) to the generally-matched materials on the signal processing board that introduces the additional junction.

[image: wikipedia's illustration of junctions in a thermocouple measurement system]

In the diagram above, uncertainty is introduced by \$T_{ref}\$ because copper/chromel and copper/alumel are required, mismatched thermocouples. The nodes in the \$T_{meter}\$ could represent copper/tin+lead/copper thermocouple junctions. However, these junctions are generally symmetric in the system, so they are of much less concern than the reference junctions. They are a source of error, but the accumulated error in the system is probably much greater than the error at the ADC input due to additional dissimilar metal junctions.

This doesn't mean that, in all precision applications, these junctions can be ignored. Precision voltage references can have their performance compromised due to varying temperature on/around the reference. See the Application Information section (page 4) of the [LTZ1000/LTZ1000A datasheet](https://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1000afe.pdf) for such a case.