# Calculating thermocouple voltage error due to ADC anti-aliasing filter resistors

Tags: thermocouple

I am designing a circuit to read thermocouple output using an ADC (AD7124-8). I am using the following circuit with 3K ohm resistors for ADC anti-aliasing filter:

[image]

I am trying to calculate the error in voltage created by the filter resistors. According to the ADC datasheet, I should expect a differential input current of 0.4 nA (see image). I am confused about how the input current contributes to error.

1. Do the above values mean that ADC readings will have an error of 4 nA * (3k+3k) = 2.4 uv due to the anti-aliasing filters?
2. Is the differential input current constant or does it change with thermocopule voltage?

Comment: This circuit won't really work. Input leakage current isn't catered for

Comment: Because your resistors are undoubtedly not copper, they add four thermocouple junctions to the  circuit.   You need to keep a thermal shield around those, to be sure they're all at the same temperature.    JonRB is correct, too, that you need some ground connection to the thermocouple wiring, or it will float to a DC level that exceeds the common-mode range of the amplifier.

Comment: @JonRB What do you mean by "input leakage current"? Is it anything other than the 0.4 nA that I mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Whit3rd I already asked a question about the other thermocouple junctions here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237299/why-are-the-junctions-where-adc-pins-connect-to-pcb-board-ignored-in-thermocoupl apparently they can be ignored for most applications. Regarding the ground connection, the ADC (AD7124-8) generates an internal bias voltage (half of VCC) which is applied to the negative leg of the ADC input for thermocouple readings. I am assuming that this creates the ground connection. Do you think this is adequate or do I still need to add a large resistor connected to ground?

Answer (score 2):

The input offset current appears to be an offset current as you suspect.

Note that the datasheet has *typical* values.

It does indeed look like there will be an [input referred error term](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sboa054) of \$V_{err} = I_{diff} \cdot R_{source(total)}\$

The typical performance curves tell an interesting story:

[image: AD7124 Current v temperature]

I would also note that there is a total input referred error term:

[image: AD7124 Input Referred Error]

Whether that input referred error graph includes the input offset current is not clear; I would assume for the purpose of managing the [error budget](http://electronicdesign.com/power/whats-all-error-budget-stuff-anyhow) (from the legendary [Bob Pease](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/)) that it is *not*.

The input currents vary with input voltage in one specific scenario, apparently:

[image: AD7124 I vs V]

As this statement is specific to this single line, I would assume that in any other mode the input currents (both absolute and offset) do not vary with input voltage.

**[Update]**

In response to the comment, it is *extremely* challenging to make a thermocouple circuit accurate to within 1 Kelvin (some might go further).

It is possible to make the differential measurement (i.e. the temperature *change*) accurate to this level with some initial span measurements (setting the thermocouple to known temperatures to calibrate out the [INL, DNL and gain errors](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/748) although you would probably need to maintain the ADC temperature constant), but an absolute accuracy at this level may simply be too much to expect.

The input voltage error term seems to be a rolled-up total of the input voltage error of the amplifier(s) and the ADC errors.

I do not know what type of thermocouple you intend to use (they each have their own transfer function), but any calibration would be best done in software as any offset circuitry will introduce its own errors.

Comment: Unfortunately the datasheet is very confusing. What about the voltage error: Is it calculated by multiplying current and filter resistance? I'm also using some protective elements on the lines like TVS and Schotkey diodes. These all add to the stray currents in the system. I'm starting to lose all hope in making thermocouple readings with an accuracy of less than 1 degree Celsius :(

Comment: While a 1 degree accuracy is challenging, because thermocouple alloys have batch-to-batch variations, you can make small-temperature-difference measurements much better than that; the DC offset of a thermocouple is accurately zero only when the delta-T is in the micro-to-millikelvin range.